# How to do Server-Side C# SQL Verification

Tags: c#, mysql

I have seen many examples use something such as this, which is client sided authentication:

```
bool legitlogin = val_log(username, password);
if (legitlogin)
 {
   Form2 objFrmMain = new Form2();
   this.Hide();
   objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
   this.Close();
   return;
 }
```

But all a program cracker has to do is simply change the if statement to

```
bool legitlogin = val_log(username, password);
if (!legitlogin)
 {
   Form2 objFrmMain = new Form2();
   this.Hide();
   objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
   this.Close();
   return;
 }
```

and then they can recompile and share the cracked version of your program in C#. I understand there is obfuscation and all, but that doesn't give enough protection.

So what is a strategy one can use to not have the check inside the client side and instead have the server do the check?

In this example, the server is a MySQL server.

Comment: Where the login validation happens doesn't really matter here, right? Just because you check the credetials against a server doesn't mean your client code will be safe.

Comment: @naslund I think the question is how would I verify a user is logged in without relying on client code? And apply server sided functions so it is far tougher to crack the program.

Comment: as long as there's business logic in your client that you don't want people to access, you can't. You might want to consider using a Web API or similar if it's fitting for the project. In my opinion it's naive to believe any kind of client logic would ever be completely safe behind your mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

## Getting your mind right about obfuscation

Ok so before giving you any sort of answer let me clarify something : nowadays, as far as .NET Programming is concerned, we've annihilated the frontier between closed-source programs and open-source programs : open-source de-obfuscators, a growing communities, more and more active members and so on. So not only any hacker can do that :

```
bool legitlogin = val_log(username, password);
if (!legitlogin)
  {
    Form2 objFrmMain = new Form2();
    this.Hide();
    objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
    return;
 }
```

but they also can take only the interesting part of your code and do this :

```
Form2 objFrmMain = new Form2();
this.Hide();
objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

in short, they can do whatever they want. I remember an old cracker on a forum who had cracked a program and had infected it using Code-Cave techniques which is really hard to do via Olly / ASM but fairly easy as far as .NET is concerned, for instance the famous open-source decompiler DnSpy can even let you edit the compiled file at C# syntax level ! ([see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXLqm.png)).

So all in all, you can't be safe.

## Mere solutions

Thus said, you can discourage hackers from decompiling / de-obfuscating your software using strong obfuscator, these obfuscator are sort of new on the market and they have been built to satisfy an higher degree of protection :

1. If you don't have money = **ConfuserEx** (Customizing it is easy since it's open source)
2. If you do have money = **BabelforNet** Or **Eazfuscator**.
3. If you do have money but only a little = **NetGuard.IO**

These 3 products are made to solve hard issue and will mostly refrain your hackers :)